# Calling ffmpeg convert from bash in iOS?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I can use something like `ffmpeg -f mpeg -i src.mpg mpeg4 dest.mp4` to convert src.mpg to dest.mp4 in bash.
And I have to port ffmpeg to iOS.
How can I use the command in iOS to complete the convert?

Comment: Is there a shell environment under iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done directly, though there is an alternate yet better way to do this, here is how:

1. Upload the video/audio file to a web server with ffmpeg support.
2. Call a php file/service any other server side language to actually execute the ffmpeg command for conversion.
3. After conversion get the file back from web server.

If you don't want to take hassle of manipulating/managing ffmpeg on web end by yourself you may try services like encoding.com etc.

Comment: That sounds like it might be *very* slow.

Comment: It is going to be extremely slow of course but for now that is the only available option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this if you are expecting to be on the app store. You cannot call any external binaries.

Link to ffmpeg libraries, or use iOS's own media conversion APIs.